In C++, what is the standard behaviour of static_cast<float>(some_double_variable)?
I can't ask new questions now, so I'm redoing this question:
How would I go about manually constructing a float from the value of a double, without casting?
Assume that the double variable's range is 0 to 1 inclusive.
I tried this, but it doesn't quite work like a cast would:
double truncate_normalized_double(double d)
{
    if (d <= 0.0)
        return 0.0;
    else if (d >= 1.0)
        return 1.0;

    static const double epsilon = pow(2.0, -23.0);
    const double remainder = fmod(d, epsilon);

    d += remainder;

    return d;
}

Any insight on how the cvtsd2ss instruction works under the hood?

Are you aware what casting in general supposed to do? Can a static_cast from double, assigned to double be optimized away?

That's the problem, other than a loss of precision, there are steps taken by the compiler, but I do not know these steps. I don't know if you read the question or not.

I did read the question where you mentioned that you tried to find the c++ standard document but couldn't find it. It seems you couldn't find the standard document. For that here is one document.

Could you give an example of "some kind of special conversion behaviour" that is not part of "a loss of precision" and that is not part of a loss of range ("clamping")? That is, what is covered by "etc."?

Let's use How is floating point conversion actually done in C++?(double to float or float to double) as a baseline that covers the details of one implementation of this cast (other implementations can be standard-compliant while differing in some details). What additional information are you interested in?

Editing a question to ask a different one isn't going to work.  If you are just clarifying your question, do so, but not by rewriting it completely.

It's the same question, which is why I left the question title as is. It's just distilled, with less clutter.

pow(2.0, -23.0) => ldexp(1.0, -23) or scalbn(1.0, -23) is much better & faster, or in case of constants like this then 0x1.0p-23 is the best

The relevant behaviours are described in the Standard's [conv.double] section:

... A prvalue of standard floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of another standard floating-point type.


2  If the source value can be exactly represented in the destination type, the result of the conversion is that exact representation.  If the source value is between two adjacent destination values, the result of the conversion is an implementation-defined choice of either of those values.  Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Both float and double (and also long double, FWIW) are "standard floating-point types", so the above applies.  When doing a narrowing conversion from double to float, many double values will not "be exactly represented in the destination type", so "if the source value is between two adjacent destination values [implementation picks one]" kicks in (and there's a loss of precision), leaving the case when the double's value is not between two representable float values as undefined behaviour.  That basically means the conversion to float has undefined behaviour for doubles with too-large absolute value: below std::numeric_limits<float>::lowest() or above std::numeric_limits<float>::max().
Of course, implementations may provide implementation-defined behaviours for situations that the Standard leaves undefined (just as POSIX provides NaN results from floating-point divisions by 0, whereas the Standard leaves that undefined).

Below the lowest is actually between 0 and a very small value; so it is well-defined, and depending on platform, result is either 0 or signed lowest. The other way, though is IMO underspecified. NaN or INF would be reasonable, but std is not explicit about it; So UB is the safest assumption.

@Red.Wave: "the lowest is actually between 0 and a very small value" - um, no.  lowest() for IEEE floats is about -3.40282e+38.

I was confused about min and lowest.

Thank you for your answer. I will think on it.

Hi @Tony-Delroy -- I put the source code up on GitHub. I edited the question to include the relevant web addresses.

@shawn_halayka: I can see your code on github, and I gather the issue is "I tried to do manual clamping, but I did not get the result that I'm looking for." - I don't see the attempt at clamping there though.  Are you aware of std::clamp?

Hi @Tony-Delroy -- thank you for your input. I redid the question to be more specific.

@shawn_halayka: redoing the question means future readers won't understand why the existing answers exist, and means you're not leaving a useful stackoverflow Q&A for the future.  It'd be better to revert the question and ask a new question about what you really want to know.

@shawn_halayka: that said, your new code shows some serious misunderstandings.  "std::numeric_limits::epsilon();" is the smallest amount by which 1.0f can be increased, but you're trying to use it to decrease tempf: as you get closer to 0, you'll be jumping by more and more representable values each time.  If you want to do this kind of thing, look at std::nextafterf, which can move tempf towards 0 by the smallest possible steps.  Horribly inefficient to do this incrementally though.

@Tony-Delroy Thank you once again for all of your insight.

@Tony-Delroy — I ended up using ostringstream and an istringstream to covert the double to a float. It’s costly, but effective.

@shawn_halayka: from my perspective, the main potential issue is that the double may be outside the range that floats can store, which - if you need to care about - you can check by comparing with lower() and max().  Otherwise the double values that can't be exactly represented as floats undergo just a tiny amount of rounding to find a nearby float.  I can't imagine why that's a problem for you.  (Taking a step back, why even use float given double's more accurate?)  Anyway, for iostreams you'll want to use setprecision to control the rounding, or you'll get grossly inaccurate conversions.

@Tony-Delroy -- I edited the question again because I found a better analogy. It works better than other techniques, but it's not quite the same as a cast. Soooo close. :(

This works:
double truncate_normalized_double(double d)
{
    if (d <= 0.0)
        return 0.0;
    else if (d >= 1.0)
        return 1.0;

    static const long long signed int mantissa_bits = 23;

    static const double epsilon = pow(2, -mantissa_bits);
    const double remainder = fmod(d, epsilon);

    d = nexttowardf(d, d - remainder);

    return d;
}

The point is to not explicitly use a cast, and it does the job. Still, is there a better version? Thank you for all of your input, people.
